# PHP function is not echoing anything in Zend Framework

Tags: javascript, php, zend-framework, echo, alert

I'm working on a website where clicking on a button will cause a variable to be initialized containing the contents of the associated text field.
However, I've noticed that none of my echo commands are executed and none of the related JS-alerts are showing up either. I have already checked the debugger and know that the action requests are being validated. It's just that nothing is showing up.

My controller:

```
public function validateuser2Action() {
    echo 'asdasdfasdf';
    $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
    if (Zend_Auth::getInstance()->hasIdentity()) {
        $model = new Application_Model_User();
        $emailAddress = $this->getRequest()->getPost("emailAddress");
        echo 'he';
    } else{
        echo 'whatever';
    }
}
```

My PHTML-file:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {      
    $(".btn-test").click(function() {
        var form_data = document.getElementById("textbox").value
        var form_url = "/workspace/validateuser2";
        var form_method = "POST";
        alert("cool");          
        $.ajax({
            url: form_url, 
            type: 'POST',      
            data: form_data,     
            success: function(data){ 
                alert(data);          
            },
            error: function(){
                alert("tpai");
            }         
        });
    })
});
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What happens if you try `echo $this->layout()->content;` ?

Comment: it turns out the second and third lines of the php function were preventing the page from rendering with the new results.